# Fill up a <div> with text and <input>

Tags: html, css, layout

How can I fill a `<div>` element with text and input so if the `<div>` get resized the input becomes shorter/longer?

[image: red: input element; green: div element]

I'm sitting since 2 hours and I just can't get it right.

Answer (score 2):

### Here's a Cross browser solution, Pure CSS

<kbd>[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/erS2j/4/)</kbd>

**HTML:**

```
<div class="Container">
    <label>text</label>
    <div class="Fill"><input type="text" /></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.Container
{
    background-color:#B5E51D;
    padding: 5px;
}
label
{
    float: left;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
.Fill
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
input
{
    width: 97%;
    margin: 0 1%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/erS2j/)**

**css**

```
.divbg{
    background-color:#B5E51D;
    padding:5px;
    overflow:hidden;
    width:100%;
    }
label{
    float:left;
    margin:0 0 0 20px;
}
input{
    float:left;
    background-color:#ED1B24;
    color:white;
    border:none;
    padding:2px 5px;
    margin:0 0 0 20px;
   min-width:200px;
}
.pull-left{
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: Its not Working. [look](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ibh51bwmn6dju8a/Screenshot%202013-10-08%2014.08.13.png)